# Cannot to replace a string to another (boolean value) - Java

Tags: java, string, boolean, replaceall

```
boolean b1 = false;
boolean b2 = true;


String s = new String(b1+""+b2);

s.replaceAll("false", "f");
s.replaceAll("true", "t");
```

Nothing is replaced. I still get "false true".
I want to replace all "false" and "true", of the String, to "f" and "t".

Im pretty sure Im not doing it the right way, and thats why I need your help, which will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `String` is immutable in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String in java is immutable, which means, once created, the value of a String object will not change.

The method replaceAll() (or almost all other methods in String class) hence are designed to return a new string rather than modifying the old one.

So the call should be made as

```
s = s.replaceAll("false", "f");
```

More on immutability is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java)

Answer (score 8):

Strings are immutable. When you do any operations on strings it creates new string. You need to assign results to a reference again

It should be something like  `s = s.replaceAll("false", "f");`

Answer (score 5):

When you calls.replaceAll("false", "f"), you're not actually mutating the String at all.  You  need to assign that value to s like so:

```
s = s.replaceAll("false", "f");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("false", "f ").replaceAll("true", "t "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write it like this:

```
 s =  s.replaceAll("false", "f");
 s =  s.replaceAll("true", "t");
```

Strings are immutable so once you declare them they cant be changed. Calling this `s.replaceAll("false", "f");` creates a new string object with `"f"` instead of `"false"`. Since you weren't assigning this new object to a variable the new string was basically lost and your left with the original string.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to realize that `String` is immutable. This means that its contents cannot be changed. In order to get the result of the replaceAll() method, you need to assign the return value to a `String`.