# How to read xml sax parser in android

Tags: android, saxparser, xmlreader

I have this code,
this is working, but problem is in this example.xml file,In this file single value single line is accepted.

```
(value>Northland College, 1411 Ellis Avenue, Ashland, Wisconsin</value>)
```

If we gave multiple line it will take only a single line read.

```
<value>Northland Community and Technical College has been in existence in one form or other since 1949,
     when the Minnesota State Board of Education approved an area vocational school for Thief River Falls.</value>
```

but i want to a multiple line read.Please give me a answer

example.xml

```
<list>
<lists name="clg_history">
    <tag>College_History</tag>
    <value>Northland Community and Technical College has been in existence in one form or other since 1949,
     when the Minnesota State Board of Education approved an area vocational school for Thief River Falls.</value>

</lists> 
<lists name="clg_courses">
    <tag>College_Courses</tag>
    <value>BTECH: CSC,IT, Civil Eng, Chemical Eng, Mechanical Eng, EEE,
     PG: MCA, MBA</value>

</lists>
<lists name="clg_address">
    <tag>College_Address</tag>
    <value>Northland College, 1411 Ellis Avenue, Ashland, Wisconsin</value>

</lists>
<lists name="clg_contact">
    <tag>College_Contact_Details</tag>
    <value>54806-3999, 
    (715) 682-1699</value>

</lists>
<lists name="clg_logo">
    <tag>College_Logo</tag>
    <value>http://www.logotypes101.com/logos/626/EC8E12391BD7F7C504C68C89A0E93484/Canisius_College.png</value>
</lists>
</list>
```

MyXMLHandler.java

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

 Boolean currentElement = false;
 String currentValue=null;
 public static SitesList sitesList = null;

 public static SitesList getSitesList() {
 return sitesList;
 }

 public static void setSitesList(SitesList sitesList) {
 MyXMLHandler.sitesList = sitesList;
 }


 @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        currentElement = true;

        if (localName.equals("list"))
        {
            /** Start */ 
            sitesList = new SitesList(); 
        }
    }    

    /** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> 
     * -- </name> )*/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        currentElement = false;

        /** set value */ 
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tag"))sitesList.setTag(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("value"))sitesList.setValue(currentValue);


    }

    /** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> 
     * -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }
}
}
```

SitesList.java

```
public class SitesList {

/** Variables */
private static ArrayList<String> tag = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

private static String ctag;
    private static String cvalue;

private static String clg_history_tag;
private static String clg_history_value;

private static String clg_address_tag;
private static String clg_address_value;

private static String clg_courses_tag;
private static String clg_courses_value;

private static String clg_contact_tag;
private static String clg_contact_value;

private static String clg_logo_tag;
private static String clg_logo_value;

/** In Setter method default it will return arraylist 
 *  change that to add  */


public ArrayList<String> getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String name) {
    tag.add(name);
}

public ArrayList<String> getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value1) {
    value.add(value1);
} 


public String getClgHistoryTag()
{
    return clg_history_tag;
}
public void setClgHistoryTag(String currentValue) {
    clg_history_tag=currentValue;
}

public String getClgHistoryValue()
{
    return clg_history_value;
}
public void setClgHistoryValue(String currentValue) {
    clg_history_value=currentValue;
}

public String getClgAddressTag()
{
    return clg_address_tag;
}
public void setClgAddressTag(String currentValue) {
    clg_address_tag=currentValue;
}

public String getClgAddressValue()
{
    return clg_address_value;
}
public void setClgAddressValue(String currentValue) {
    clg_address_value=currentValue;
}

public String getClgCoursesTag()
{
    return clg_courses_tag;
}
public void setClgCoursesTag(String currentValue) {
    clg_courses_tag=currentValue;
}

public String getClgCoursesValue()
{
    return clg_courses_value;
}
public void setClgCoursesValue(String currentValue) {
    clg_courses_value=currentValue;
}

public String getClgContactTag()
{
    return clg_contact_tag;
}
public void setClgContactTag(String currentValue) {
    clg_contact_tag=currentValue;
}

public String getClgContactValue()
{
    return clg_contact_value;
}
public void setClgContactValue(String currentValue) {
    clg_contact_value=currentValue;
}

public String getClgLogoTag()
{
    return clg_logo_tag;
}
public void setClgLogoTag(String currentValue) {
    clg_logo_tag=currentValue;
}

public String getClgLogoValue()
{
    return clg_logo_value;
}
public void setClgLogoValue(String currentValue) {
    clg_logo_value=currentValue;
}
}
```

Xmlparser.java

```
public class Xmlparser extends Activity {
SitesList sitesList = null;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisLoveBacon) {
    super.onCreate(TravisLoveBacon);
    // making it full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    TextView tag[];
    TextView value[];


    try {

    /** Handling XML */
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
     InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example));

    /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
    MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
    xr.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
    sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;


    //System.out.println("");
    /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
    tag = new TextView[sitesList.getTag().size()];
    System.out.println("tags"+sitesList.getTag().size());
    value = new TextView[sitesList.getValue().size()];
    System.out.println("values"+sitesList.getValue().size());


    /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */

    sitesList.setClgHistoryTag(sitesList.getTag().get(0));
    sitesList.setClgHistoryValue(sitesList.getValue().get(0));

    sitesList.setClgCoursesTag(sitesList.getTag().get(1));
    sitesList.setClgCoursesValue(sitesList.getValue().get(1));

    sitesList.setClgAddressTag(sitesList.getTag().get(2));
    sitesList.setClgAddressValue(sitesList.getValue().get(2));

    sitesList.setClgContactTag(sitesList.getTag().get(3));
    sitesList.setClgContactValue(sitesList.getValue().get(3));

    sitesList.setClgLogoTag(sitesList.getTag().get(4));
    sitesList.setClgLogoValue(sitesList.getValue().get(4));


    System.out.println(sitesList.getClgHistoryValue());
    System.out.println(sitesList.getClgCoursesValue());
    System.out.println(sitesList.getClgAddressValue());
    System.out.println(sitesList.getClgContactValue());
    System.out.println(sitesList.getClgLogoValue());

}
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I suspect the linefeed in the characters is giving problems. Try change your character() method in the xml handler to:

```
currentValue = new String(ch, start, length).replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
```

Comment: What is that(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n). Here is regularExpression

Comment: Replace carriage-return/linefeed with single whitespace.

Comment: Experiment with the `replaceAll()`, some good suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633710/removing-backslash-and-newline-character-occurring-together-in-java